# Hadoop DFS Error when coping file from local to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
2009/08/10 11:33:07 [INFO] - Copying local:/ X/Y/Z.txt to DFS:/X/Y/Z.txt

2009/08/10 11:33:07 [INFO] -    put:  
org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.AccessControlException: Permission
denied: user=superman, access=WRITE, inode="":big-build:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x

2009/08/10 11:33:08 [FATAL] - DFS error:  can't copy /X/Y/Z.txt into /X/Y:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says it might be simply that you don't have the write permission on the target location?

Answer (score 0):

Post your configuration files. Is this is a single node setup or multinode setup. You can see http://blog.abhinavmathur.net/2013/01/experience-with-setting-multinode.html